# How to calculate this integral using dominated convergence theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

> I want to calculate
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{n^{-1}}^n \frac{n^2xe^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2}\,dx\tag{1}$$

I have used two approach but get different answer.

(1) take $y=n^2x^2$, then 
$$(1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^{n^4}\frac{e^{-y}}{2(1+\frac{y}{n^2})}\,dy$$

$\frac{e^{-y}}{2(1+\frac{y}{n^2})}1_{[1,n^4]}(y)$ is dominated by $e^{-y}$ which is integrable, then by dominated convergence theorem we get $(1)=(2e)^{-1}$

(2) take $g(n)=\frac{n^2xe^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2}$, "differentiate" wrt $n$
$$g'(n)=\frac{2(1-n^2x^2)nxe^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2}\tag{3}$$

since $x\in[n^{-1},n]$, then $g'(n)<0$, so for all $x\in[n^{-1},n]$, $g(n)\le g(1)=\frac{xe^{-x^2}}{1+x^2}$ , then
$$\frac{n^2xe^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2}1_{[n^{-1},n]}(x)\le\frac{xe^{-x^2}}{1+x^2}\tag{2}$$

which is integrable, then by dominated convergence theorem, we get $(1)=0$

I am confused about what's wrong with my application of dominated convergence theorem, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: OK : DCT is Dominated Convergence Theorem : please if you use acronyms (why not) recall at first what they are (this acronym is very seldom used!!!). DCT for example can designate the (widely used, for exmple for Jpeg compression) Discrete Cosine Transform.

Comment: @JeanMarie, apologize, I was under the delusion that DCT is a common notation.

Comment: Note that $g'(n)=\frac{2(1-n^2x^2)nxe^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2}=0$ when $n=1/x$.  And at the maximum, $g(1/x)=\frac{e^{-1}}{x(1+x^2)}$, which is not integrable for $x\in [0,1]$.

Comment: @Dr.MV, but I didn't use $g(1/x)$ as the dominating function, I used RHS of (2) instead, which is integrable for $x\in(0,\infty)$

Comment: That function does not dominate the integrand unfortunately.

Comment: @Dr.MV, actually I agree with you, but can you help me point out what's wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: The pointwise limit is identically zero. So if dominated convergence applies directly, then the limit would be zero. But actually it doesn't apply directly: the maximum of $n^2 x e^{-n^2 x^2} \geq n^2 n^{-1} e^{-1}=n e^{-1}$. (I just got this by plugging in $x=1/n$, which I did to remove the dependence of the exponential piece on $n$. Explicitly finding the exact maximum is *not* usually a good idea.) So the maximum of your overall quantity is at least $n (2e)^{-1}$. So from here you should expect that there is no integrable function which is larger than your functions on $[0,1]$.

Comment: (Cont.) To make this precise you would need to estimate the size of the interval around the maximum where the function is at least, say, half the maximum. This calculation works out, but it isn't very illuminating. Your initial approach of changing variables and then using dominated convergence afterwards is correct.

Comment: @Ian thanks，your comment is quite illuminative, you told me when to find the dominating function and when to change the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first approach is correct.  However, there is a flaw in the second one.

Note that $g'(n)=\frac{2(1-n^2x^2)nxe^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2}=0$ when $n=1/x$.  And at the maximum, $g(1/x)=\frac{e^{-1}}{x(1+x^2)}$, which is not integrable for $x\in [0,1]$.

> The proposed dominating function, $\frac{xe^{-x^2}}{1+x^2}$ does not, in fact, dominate $g(n)=\frac{n^2xe^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2}$ for all $x\in [1/n,n]$.
>
> At $x=1/n$, we have $g(n)=ne^{-1}> \frac1n e^{-1/n^2}$ for $n>1$.

---

One way around this difficulty is to write

$$\begin{align}
\int_{1/n}^n\frac{n^2xe^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2}\,dx&=\int_{1/n}^n n^2xe^{-n^2x^2}\,dx-\int_{1/n}^n\frac{n^2x^3e^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac12 (e^{-1}-e^{-n^4})-\int_{1/n}^1\frac{n^2x^3e^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2}\,dx-\int_{1}^n\frac{n^2x^3e^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2}\,dx \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Now, let $h_n(x)=\frac{n^2x^3e^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2}$.  Then, it is easy to show that $h_n(x)\le \frac{xe^{-1}}{1+x^2}$.  So,  the DCT guarantees that the first integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ approaches $0$.

For the second integral, we note that for $x\ge 1$, $h_n(x)\le \frac{x^3e^{-x}}{1+x^2}$.  Therefore, the DCT guarantees that the second integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ also approaches $0$.

Hence, we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{1/n}^n\frac{n^2xe^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2}\,dx=\frac{e^{-1}}{2}}$$

as expected!

Comment: thanks, your counter example is correct, but I still don't know what's wrong with my reasoning (not the conclusion ). I want to know why my approach to get the extreme value by taking derivatives fails. more precisely, why the statement between (2) and (3) is wrong?

Comment: Your proposed dominating function unfortunately does not dominate.

Comment: yes, it does not dominate, but why I "can" deduce that it dominates the integrand using the procedure in the post? There must be something wrong between (2) and (3), but I can't find it out...

Comment: The post states that $g(n)\le g(1)$; this is an incorrect conclusion.  I've added quite a bit to my post and I hope that it helps.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark

Comment: REALLY THANKS, I think I need a little time to think it over, one question is why your $h_n\le ...$ holds,  for example, $nx>1$ in the 1st integral, so?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  The maximum of $h_n(x)$ occurs when $x=1/n$, which is the same as $n=1/x$.  Let $n=1/x$ and you obtain the dominating function.  ;-))